# What does the "Save password to Google?" do?

Tags: google, password

I'm on Android 10 and and after installing the `Uber` App, I get the *"Save password to Google?"* prompt. But since I'm a not a huge fan of the Google megapoly, I'm reluctant to say *yes*, when I have no idea where my password will end up.

**What does the "Save password to Google?" actually do? (and where is it saved?)**

Comment: Related: [Google Account Help - Sync passwords across your devices](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6197437?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid)

Comment: Google app -> Manage your account -> Security -> Password Manager, click on the gear, they are listed there. You can also switch it on/of by enabling/disabling "Offer to save passwords" from the same place.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I have 14 different "Google apps" on my phone, which one are you talking about?

Comment: @AndrewT. As (ususal?) Googles own pages are outdated. The path shown in the no.1 [item](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6197437?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid) doesn't exist: `On your Android phone or tablet, open your device's * Settings app > Google > Google Account.`

Comment: There is one called Google, open that one (not Google something).

Comment: Ok, I found it under the following path (when using **MIUI Global 12.0.8**): 
`Settings > Privacy > "Autofill service from Google" > Passwords`. But this still do not answer as to **where** these passwords are stored.